# Can I add a Distribution List as a member to another Distribution List?

Tags: active-directory, exchange

I'd like to add some distribution lists as members of a different distribution list to make things easier. Is this possible? If so, can somebody tell me how to set this up?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are talking about adding them through Exchange. If this is the case than yes, you can add distribution lists to other distribution lists. To do this on Exchange 07: open up the Exchange Management Console, under recipient configuration select distribution groups, right click the group you want to add other groups to and select properties, navigate to members and click add. This can also be done with personal distribution lists through Outlook, let me know if you need help setting these up.

Comment: The problem I was actually having was my distribution group was setup as global rather than universal so it wasn't finding the DLs. However, your answer is the correct answer to what I actually phrased the question as so I will give you the check.